# Drupal memcache problem - perhaps misconfigured?

Tags: 6, caching

I'm trying to configure `memcache` w/ my `pressflow`. I followed instruction from 
[Memcache API and Integration | drupal.org](https://drupal.org/project/memcache) site yet whenever I'm trying to access /memcache.php to see stats, I always see `Free` is 100% and `Used` is 0%.

I'm not sure what to do to troubleshoot it? I know when I stop service and I try to access `memcache.php` it says it can not connect to server, so that part is working...

*** UPDATE ***

I did some testing of memcached itself by running `/usr/bin/memslap --servers=127.0.0.1:11211` and that filled memcache by 4.64%, so this proves memcached itself is working as it should, now back to drupal's settings.php configuration: here is attached copy of lines that are related to memcache:

```
# grep \'cache_ /var/www/html/current/sites/XXX/settings.php 
$conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/contrib/memcache/memcache.inc';
$conf['cache_default_class'] = 'MemCacheDrupal';
$conf['cache_class_cache_form'] = 'DrupalDatabaseCache';
#
```

*** UPDATE 2 ***

this is part of installation's document:

The available memcached servers are specified in $conf in settings.php. If you do not specify any servers, memcache.inc assumes that you have a memcached instance running on `127.0.0.1:11211`. If this is true, and it is the only memcached instance you wish to use, no further configuration is required.

... in my case this *IS* true, I only have one instance and it's running on 127.0.0.1:11211.

So there (I just specified what according to documentation I really shouldn't, and since I'm specifying `memcache` nodes, I'm going to include both of nodes. I'm able to telnet to both of nodes from either of nodes):

```
$conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/contrib/memcache/memcache.inc';
$conf['cache_default_class'] = 'MemCacheDrupal';
$conf['cache_class_cache_form'] = 'DrupalDatabaseCache';
$conf['memcache_servers'] = array(
        '6app02a:11211' => 'default',
        '6app02b:11211' => 'default'
);
$conf['memcache_bins'] = array(
        'cache' => 'default'
);
```

Comment: How are your results when you connect another app to use memcache? And what do you see when you try external, non-drupal monitoring tool? These are basic cross-tests to identify source of a problem.

Comment: I don't use memcache for any other apps other then pressflow nor do I use drupal monitoring tool (or even aware of any), which tool are you referring too? how can I see memcache through drupal?

Comment: [memaslap](http://docs.libmemcached.org/bin/memaslap.html) is example memcached load generator for testing. There is also [a list of tools](https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/Tools) on Google Code.

Comment: are we testing if memcached is up and running? yes it is! I'm able to telnet to port and issue command (flush_all) on which I get response OK, so as far as server itself I think it's configured fine, the main thing is to get drupal to play w/ memcache.

Comment: How do you know anything is able to actually fill up memcached, write to it, if all you have seen is used 0% ?

Comment: ok, I just ran `/usr/bin/memslap --servers=127.0.0.1:11211` and then hit my `memcache.php` and I see usage went up to 6.46%, so seems like memcache itself is fine, it's something to do w/ drupal connecting to it, that proves my point as before that I misconfigured something somewhere..

Comment: OK, so post a screenshot of your config in Drupal and let's be about it. I had bad experience with memcached server misconfigured on the server side, so that's first thing worth testing for me. You're lucky it's not your case.

Comment: I pasted here: http://pastebin.com/4YUdCdqD memcache realated lines, which I copy from line #7

Comment: Add link to your question, with a note that you can fill up memcache with external software and monitoring works... And I'll see what can I read there.

Comment: @alexus Your settings.php pastebin doesn't show that you've included `$conf['memcache_servers']`

Comment: I can't see$conf['memcache_servers'] section in your config. So either is very very buggy or you didn't posted all configuration. Also, paste it directly into question as a code block, no need for pastebin, really.